# getCommentedEntity returns null

Tags: 8, comments

I have a comments page set up and when I devel the page for a specific comment I see the getcommentedentity method.
[image]

I am trying to get the commented entity details using the below code in my VBO action file:

```
public function execute(ContentEntityInterface $entity = NULL) {
    $comment = $entity->get('comment_body')->getValue();
    $commentid = $entity->get('cid')->getValue();
    $var = $commentid->getCommentedEntity;
    dpm($var);
}
```

But I see error for this method. Not sure where it's wrong. Can someone tell me where the mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `$entity` is a comment entity as shown in the screenshot, use:

```
$commented_entity = $entity->getCommentedEntity();
```